# After loading the urdf model in gazebo, there is no `map` frame on the tf tree

Tags: gazebo, transforms, ros-kinetic

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I defined a robot model with the `urdf` file, but after gazebo reads the urdf file, I check out the `tf` tree and find that there is no `map` frame on the `tf` tree. I wanna figure out how I can generate a map frame when I spawn my robot model in gazebo. Any advice will be appreciated.

Screenshot of tf tree:
[image: Imgur]

My launch file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Launch this file to spawn cambot model in gazebo. -->
<launch>
    <!-- these are the arguments you can pass this launch file, for example paused:=true -->
    <arg name="paused" default="false" />
    <arg name="use_sim_time" default="true" />
    <arg name="gui" default="true" />
    <arg name="headless" default="false" />
    <arg name="debug" default="false" />
    <!-- We resume the logic in empty_world.launch, changing only the name of the world to be launched -->
    <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
        <arg name="debug" value="$(arg debug)" />
        <arg name="gui" value="$(arg gui)" />
        <arg name="paused" value="$(arg paused)" />
        <arg name="use_sim_time" value="$(arg use_sim_time)" />
        <arg name="headless" value="$(arg headless)" />
    </include>
    <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro --inorder $(find cambot_description)/urdf/cambot.urdf.xacro" />
    <node name="urdf_spawner" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" respawn="false" output="screen" args="-urdf -model cambot -param robot_description"></node>
</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/22217/after-loading-the-urdf-model-in-gazebo,-there-is-no-%60map%60-frame-on-the-tf-tree./) by [duhyu1](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4878/duhyu1/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-04-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

A transform between map and odom is published by any of the SLAM package e.g. [gmapping](http://wiki.ros.org/gmapping), [RTABmap](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros) or GoogleCartographer. You can use any of them  to get a occupancy grid. The occupancy grid will be published on some topic (default topics are different for different mapping packages. You can check the documentation) and a transform between map to odom will be published by default.

---

Originally posted by [shiveshkhaitan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/8978/shiveshkhaitan/) with karma: 16 on 2019-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [duhyu1](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4878/duhyu1/) on 2019-04-03**:
Now I know the reason: the robot model I generated in gazebo was started in empty world(`roslaunch gazebo_ros empty_world.launch`), causing the data of the simulated laser to be all 0. Now I generate the robot in a world with some obstacles(`roslaunch gazebo_ros shapes_world.launch`), cartographer will update the `map->odom` transform on the `tf` tree according to the non-zero `sensor_msgs/LaserScan` data.